# AC belt & Serpentine belt

Tags: serpentine-belt

I had my ac belt and my serpentine belt chaged on my 2007 M35 now my car is making a horrible noise.When I start my car then after a few minutes it stop.But I notice if my ac is on it makes this noise also what could that be?

Comment: Could be that your belts are missaligned. Maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cW_wpE3hG5k) video can help you identify the problem. Or [this](http://www.daycoproducts.com/diagnosing-misalignment-and-belt-noise) page could help you out aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When belts are installed, they need to be adjusted (depending on the vehicle) or they can slip causing a squealing sound.

In some cases, the new belt is not stretched like the old one. This puts added pressure on the idler pulley. That can create a lot of noise if the pulley is going bad. They should have checked it.

From what you describe, it sounds like they improperly adjusted the belts and they are slipping. Take it back to the shop that did the work.

Answer (score -1):

Had to have a different set of belts put on the one they replaced them with was cheap thats why they made the nosie.Thanks